# Soft Keyboard cuts off the bottom part of my EditText/TextInputEditText Control

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am experience the challenge shown in the image below;

[image: Soft Keyboard overlaps EditText Control]

The only time i do not experience this challenge is when the EditText control doesn't have the drawable used to achieve the border around the control.

I have tried the following suggestions and non seems to fix it;

**Suggestion 1**

```
@Override
//public void setBackground(Drawable background) {  
public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
    int pl = getPaddingLeft();
    int pt = getPaddingTop();
    int pr = getPaddingRight();
    int pb = getPaddingBottom();

    super.setBackgroundResource(resid);

    this.setPadding(pl, pt, pr, pb);
}
```

**Suggestion 2**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**Suggestion 3**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

How do i get the EditText control to seat about the soft keyboard?

**Update 1**

A section of my Layout;

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=" "
    >
    <!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textControlMarginBottom"
        android:hint="@string/userNameHint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/txtUserName"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/txtUserName"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/txtPassword"
        style="@style/EditTextViewSingleRowStyle" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

```
<style name="EditTextViewSingleRowStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/textViewHeight</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/textViewTopPadding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/textViewBottomPadding</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_text_control_edit</item>
    <item name="android:cursorVisible">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/controlTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/controlTextViewHint</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor</item>
    <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/controlTextSize</item>
</style>
```

**Solution**

I had set a fixed height for the EditText/TextInputEditText control. I change it from `android:layout_height='48dp'` to `android:layout_height='match_content'`

Comment: have you tried `Scrollview` as your parent in your layout

Comment: can you please post your xml?

Comment: It depends what you have in your XML file. I mean layout type, view alignments and other stuff... @Tebo

Comment: @vikassingh I have tried the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Tebo can you try my answer

Comment: @Tebo try my answer and it's working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set a fixed height for the EditText/TextInputEditText control. I change it from `android:layout_height='48dp'` to `android:layout_height='match_content'`

Comment: There is no `match_content` in Android.

Comment: Yeah I passed I understood it. It was later changed.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your activity `ScrollView` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >  


</ScrollView>
```

Then inside your `activity` make sure you are doing something like this(this code is just to demonstrate where to use 
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);)`

For example :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    final EditText edittext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edittext.requestLayout();
            MyActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);

            return false; 
        } 
    }); 


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parent layout as `RelativeLayout`
and then add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your `TextInputEditText` like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="username ">
        <!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            style="@style/EditTextViewSingleRowStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/edittextBorder"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/txtUserName"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/txtUserName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can customized your `TextInputEditText` by adding this edittextBorder.xml in your drawable folder..

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:height="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:top="15dp" />

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#f2f1f1" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#b90917" />

    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

and output like this..

[image]

Comment: You sure it worked with `android:layout_height="46dp" ` for me that was the problem.

Comment: I will still test out your answer later and vote up if it works.